# 4 USB to Ethernet Converters Issue

Tags: usb

I take 4 USB to Ethernet converter (IP address: 10.12.1.251~254) do the test found when 1 data line offline (just moved the CAT5e wiring_10.12.1.254) the RPI3 detect it, the windoes no this IP address (10.12.1.254). It is correct. but why i still can ping that IP adress (10.12.1.254), why ?any idea?

Comment: What's a "4 USB to Ethernet converter", can you provide a link?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Do you have 4 wired ethernet connections? Where are they all connected to? Do you have 4 laptops connected to the RasPi? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Comment: Thanks your reply
My setup and link as below 
USB<->converter 1<->Eth1:10.12.1.251<->Cat5e _1<-> Laptop1: 10.12.1.200
USB<->converter 2<-> Eth2:10.22.1.252<->Cat5e_2<-> Laptop2: 10.22.1.200
USB<->converter 3<-> Eth3: 10.33.1.253<->Cat5e_3<-> Laptop3: 10.33.1.200
USB<->converter 4<->Eth4: 10.44.1.253<->Cat5e_4<-> Laptop4: 10.44.1.200
Connected to a different laptop, I removed the eth2 to laptop 2 that cat5e cable (Cat5e_2) of the laptop and reboot RPI3, found laptop2 10.22.1.200 can still ping to Eth2: 10.22.1.252.

Comment: Every time reboot of RPI3, Eth1~ Eth4 IP address will be changed, for sample
Previous setting as below
Eth1:10.11.1.251
Eth2:10.22.1.252
Eth3: 10.33.1.253
Eth4: 10.44.1.254
After reboot of RPI3 the IP address will be changed (Eth1 IP address changed to Eth3, Eth2 IP address changed to Eth4) 
Eth1: 10.33.1.253
Eth2:10.44.1.254
Eth3: 10.11.1.251
Eth4: 10.22.1.252

Comment: @SamHsu - you should edit the extra information into your question (there is an "edit" link under the tags list). Information in comments can easily be lost from default views. Also in the question text you can use formatting to make the info dump more readable: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting. In this instance a picture of your arrangement may also be useful to make it more obvious you have four USB NICs not one multi-port USB NIC.